# Is it possible to add a white space at start of my commands?

Tags: command-line

I would tweak my custom commands using a whitespace in Linux terminal. I have used `echo "    " + cmd` but it doesn't works. If someone has any hint, would be great,
thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish this?  Why not just press space, and then type your command?  Are you saying you want the output of the command to start with an additional space?  Trying to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to type like this:

```
echo " "$(command)
```